# How to know Site Collections belong to different Web Application?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have two site collections

https://www.sharepoint.com/teams/new1

https://www.sharepoint.com/sites/new2

One is under /teams/ other is under /sites/

Do they belong to different web application?

Comment: Please refer this link. This will help you understand the SharePoint URL structure. -- http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2010/03/25/sharepoint-url-basics-aspx/

Comment: Thanks Rohit, it resolved my query.

Comment: Welcome Pushpendra :)